# Django / Bootstrap 4 / Blog Post || How to get responsive images?

Tags: html, django, image, bootstrap-4, responsive

I've been able to add images to my post with ckeditor which is great but I can't seem to get the images to shrink and be responsive like the rest of the content/text in my post. I've tried a few tutorials and played around with things but nothing seems to work. Thanks.

Here is my BASE.HTML

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'portfolio_app/main.css' %}">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Davi Silveira DoP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main role="main">
        {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
                <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
                    {{ message }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </main>
    <footer class="text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="float-right">
                <a href="#">Back to top</a>
            </p>
            <p class="text-muted">Davi Silveira &copy; 2020</p>
            <p>Associated with <a href="https://www.facebook.com/silveirabrothers/">Silveira Brothers Films</a></p>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

BLOG.HTML

```
{% extends "portfolio_app/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="jumbotron content-section">
                <small class="text-muted">
                    "Look at the natural light, when it's right and when it's beautiful. Don't mock with it, just use it as it is. If you must make any change, make it deliberately, make it delicately." -Douglas Kirkland 
                </small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="container">
            <div  class="col-md-12">
                <article class="content-section">
                    <img class="rounded-square article-img" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}">
                    <div class="body">
                        <div class="article-metadata">
                            <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' post.author.username %}">{{ post.author }}</a>
                            <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted|date:'F d, Y' }}</small>
                        </div>
                        <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">{{ post.title|safe }}</a></h2>
                        <p class="article-content">{{ post.content|safe|truncatewords:30 }}</p>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="container">
        {% if is_paginated %}

            {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page=1">First</a>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
            {% endif %}

            {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
                {% if page_obj.number == num %}
                    <a class="btn btn-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
                {% elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and num < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

            {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">Last</a>
            {% endif %}

        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

POST_DETAIL.HTML

```
{% extends "portfolio_app/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="py-5 bg-light">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <article class="content-section">
                        <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ object.author.profile.image.url }}">
                        <div class="body">
                            <div class="article-metadata">
                                <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' object.author.username %}">{{ object.author }}</a>
                                <small class="text-muted">{{ object.date_posted|date:'F d, Y' }}</small>
                                {% if object.author == user %}
                                    <div>
                                        <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'post-update' object.id %}">Update Post</a>
                                        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'post-delete' object.id %}">Delete Post</a>
                                    </div>
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
                            <h2 class="article-title">{{ object.title }}</h2>
                            <p class="article-content">{{ object.content }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

POST_FORM.HTML

```
{% extends "portfolio_app/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
        <div class="container col-md-6">
            <div class="content-section">
                <div class="content-section">
                    <form method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <legend class="border-bottom md-4">Blog Post</legend>
                            {{ form.media }}
                            {{ form|crispy }}
                        </fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post!</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

What am I missing..? Thank you again for your help.

Comment: can you show response of ckeditor which you are using in html.